# Double output for long to wide transformation of sequential data

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, output

The data is as follows:
Random characters so the bot lets me post my edit:sdnasdinaiwefjaepofj

```
    ID|Character_date|Flag|SASDATE
    
    A |2012_01       |0/1 |MONYY
    
    A |2012_02       |0/1 |MONYY
    
    .................
    
    F |2012_02       |0/1 |MONYY
```

I want to transform it to  be wide but with  12 months intervals.

So for each date there would be an account with 12 columns each indicating a date of flag activation with a horizon of 12 months

```
ID|Character_date|SASDATE|Flag_actived_date1  |Flag_actived_date2  |Flag_actived_date3  

|Flag_actived_date4  |Flag_actived_date5  |Flag_actived_date6  |Flag_actived_date7  |...

A |2012_01   |MONYY  |(if flag 1 the date)|....

B |2012_01   |MONYY  |(if flag 1 the date)|....

C |2012_01   |MONYY  |(if flag 1 the date)|....

...............

A |2012_02   |MONYY  |(if flag 1 the date)|....

B |2012_02   |MONYY  |(if flag 1 the date)|....

C |2012_02   |MONYY  |(if flag 1 the date)|....
```

```
data pd_base_ttd2;
set pd_base_std end=eof;
format ttd best12. def_count best12.;
ARRAY def_dates{0:13} def_dates1-def_dates14;
;retain count def_dates1-def_dates14 def_count;
by descending credit_id ;
    if first.credit_id then do;
        count=0;
        def_count=0;
        do i=0 to 13;def_dates{i}=0;end;
    ;end;
    if default_flag=1 then do;
        def_dates{mod(count,12)}=date_obs;
        count=count+1;
        def_count=def_count+1;
    ;end;
    else if default_flag=0 then count=count+1;
    if last.credit_id or mod(count,12)=11 then output;
run;

DATA pd_base_std;
        if 0 then set pd_base_ttd2(keep=credit_id YYYY_mm) pd_base_std;
        if _n_ eq 1 then do;
            declare hash h_cf(dataset:'pd_base_ttd2',hashexp:15, multidata:'Y');
            h_cf.defineKey('credit_id','YYYY_mm');
            h_cf.defineData('credit_id','YYYY_mm');
            h_cf.defineDone(); 
        end;
        set pd_base_std;
            rc_cf = h_cf.find();
            do while(rc_cf=0);
            rc_cf=h_cf.find_next();
            end;
        if rc_cf ne 0 then output;
        drop rc_cf;
run;
proc sort data=pd_base_std ; by descending  credit_id ; run;

data pd_base_all; set pd_base_ttd2 pd_base_all; run;
```

And repeat that over and over.
What I want is something like this.:

```
data pd_base_ttd2 pd_base_std ;
do untill(eof);
    set pd_base_std end=eof;
    format ttd best12. def_count best12.;
    ARRAY def_dates{0:13} def_dates1-def_dates14;
    ;retain count def_dates1-def_dates14 def_count;
    by descending credit_id ;
    if first.credit_id then do;
        count=0;
        def_count=0;
        do i=0 to 13;def_dates{i}=0;end;
    ;end;
    if default_flag=1 then do;
        def_dates{mod(count,12)}=date_obs;
        count=count+1;
        def_count=def_count+1;
    ;end;
    else if default_flag=0 then count=count+1;
    if last.credit_id or mod(count,12)=11 then
    do;
     output to pd_base_ttd2;
     rc=1;
    end;
end;
if rc=1 then delete;
do _N_=1 by 1 untill(last.credit_id);
    set pd_base_std end=ef;
    by descending credit_id;
    output pd_base_std ;
end;    
run;
```

Comment: If the pivot is for reporting purposes, consider using Proc TRANSPOSE (`table <down-vars>,<across-vars>`) or Proc REPORT (`define <var>/across` )

Comment: @Richard It will undergo array processing after.

Comment: Do you have multiple rows for a given id/character_date ? If not you will have only one possible flag activated date for a given id/character_date combination.  Show some actual sample data instead of abstract.  Also your 'wanted' shows two rows for `A |2012_02 `, is that correct?

Comment: @Richard No, that was a typo. I figured it out. but basically I wanted a long data set with a lead of 12 months for each observation available.

Answer (score 0):

I over complicated my approaches, probably eager to test out stuff I read about.

```
data pd_base_ttd2 pd_base_std ;
do _N_=1 by 1 until(last.credit_id);
    set lgd.pd_base_std end=eof;
    format ttd best12. def_count best12.;
    ARRAY def_dates{0:13} def_dates1-def_dates14;
    retain count def_dates1-def_dates14 def_count;
    by descending credit_id ;
    if first.credit_id then do;
        count=0;
        def_count=0;
        do i=0 to 13;def_dates{i}=0;end;
    ;end;
    if default_flag=1 then do;
        def_dates{mod(count,12)}=date_obs;
        count=count+1;
        def_count=def_count+1;
    ;end;
    else if default_flag=0 then count=count+1;
    if last.credit_id or mod(count,12)=11 then output pd_base_ttd2;
    else output pd_base_std ;   
end;
run;
```

Now  the question is how to this without a macro loop but instead making sas read the set again and again? Like: ok you reached the end, now start over, it would also have to be able to keep the descending order of both `credit_id` and `YYYY_MM`.

Comment: You can probably use arrays instead of macro and multiple passes of the data.  You might need a pre-step to compute the widest id (largest number of across variables needed for an id/mon combination).